# Analyze log files from many languages using a single tool. And recommendations of logging frameworks

Tags: c#, php, c++, logging

We have a system build on lots of languages. The ones we are interested in logging, in order of priority, are:

- C/C++
- PHP
- C#
- Bash
- Java

Wish list:

- If it is possible, we would like **logging** to be achieved from the **above languages** in such a way that we may use a **single log viewing tool** for all of them. Ideally they would be in the *same* format, but next to that in as few formats as possible and readable from as many log file viewers as possible.
- If it is possible logging to a single log file or a set of log files would be nice. With a possibility to filter based on the source language that is being logged.
- We would like to **copy** the **log** files (or should be log to a database and copy it instead?) **from multiple servers** to a single location. So that we can **analyze** the **log files** from **many servers** at the **same time** (to see if any of our servers execute a certain piece legacy code for example).
- Being able to **change logging level at runtime** would be nice.

Thank you for reading! It's quite a complex problem, I hope someone has wrestled with it before and has some valuable information!

Comment: Not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but it wouldn't hurt to take a look at http://www.logverse.com.

Comment: It sounds like you care about log formats.  What's hard about having a library of logging functions in each language that write consistent logs?   Or are you concerned with the problem of inserting logging code in all these languages, across a huge source base?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using linux, syslog is great! The project I am working on right now uses syslog for most of our logging; everything goes to the same place (/var/log/messages) and you are able to log from many different tools all to the same log file. Apparently you can also use syslog to log to a remote server.

Otherwise if you are on windows you might consider writing to the event log.